# Static member reclaiming memory and recovering from an exception

Tags: c++, exception, operator-overloading, new-operator

This is my assignment question

> Create a class with its own operator new. This operator should
>   allocate 5 objects, and on 5th 'run out of memory' and throw an
>   exception. Also add a static member function that reclaims this
>   memory. Now create a main () with try block and catch clause that
>   calls the memory-restoration routine. Put these inside a while loop to
>   demonstrate recovering from an exception and continuing execution.

Now I don't want the program, but I am confused with this question. I can handle new operator overloading, but as asked I should create a static member "release()". And if I have to recover in catch, how do I recover? I mean what object should I delete.
Or my prototype for release() is wrong?

Edit:
Also if I have to delete, which of the 5 objects can I delete? And deleting any object would in fact be incorrect. I see no way of recovery.

Comment: There are few days of holidays, after which i may have to ask my sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would need something like a static list of addresses in your class. Whenever new is called you store the address of the memory block in that list. Then in your release method you go through the static list and free the memory plus throw the exception.

Comment: Following your suggestion i am adding static void* allocatedObjects[5]; to my class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange assignment. If I understand this right, you'd have to store the addresses of the objects created inside your `operator new` somewhere the `release()`-function can find them.

Comment: Indeed i am struggling with address thing.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question is that the implementation of the `new` operator in your class should track the acquired memory, so that your `release` method (I would use your same signature), can reclaim the memory.

That approach is used in some generational garbage collectors where during each generation memory is acquired from a pool, and once the execution for the generation completes a single call will release all the memory, avoiding fragmentation and the cost of managing the free list (the allocator can provide increasing addresses inside the pool, the deallocator just ignores the data in the pool) Note that this particular type of pool can be efficient, but its use is limited to POD types.

Comment: this question has only educational value and i don't think real world solutions like pooling is required.

Comment: @VinayakGarg I was not trying to suggest pooling as part of the solution, just point out that this might not only be theoretical, as the same type of approach is applied to tackle specific problems. Another similar example closer to your problem of managing exceptions could be transactional memory, where the allocator (more complex than you need) would start a new "generation" when the transaction starts, and if an exception is thrown before the commit, then memory (and the associated state) would be backtracked... I used to like knowing that I was learning something useful in the past :)

Comment: yeah the educational value will be valuable later. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

The static member should have an allocate a release and reclaim methods.

```
struct AllocatorPool
{
     char*  allocate(size_t size);
     void   deallocate(char* ptr);

     void   reclaimPool();

     // Other stuff to handle memory management.
};

class T
{
      static  AllocatorPool    memoryForOjectsOfTypeT;


     // You new method here that gets memory from `memoryForOjectsOfTypeT`
};
```