# stuck in infinite loop in deallocating memory

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, memory-management

i had asked help on this question here [Static member reclaiming memory and recovering from an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833196/static-member-reclaiming-memory-and-recovering-from-an-exception)

the program below is to allocate memory using own new operator. I have to throw exception on 5th object allocation and recover by freeing up memory (strange question i know, but it is assignment)

i have written the code here. allocation works, but when i try to call delete (through option '2') i get stuck in infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class object
{
    int data;
    static int count;
    static void* allocatedObjects[5];
public:
    object() {  }
    void* operator new(size_t);
    void operator delete(void *);
    void static release();
    void static printCount()
    {
        cout << count << '\n';
    }
    ~object()
    {
        release();
    }
};

int object::count = 0;
void* object::allocatedObjects[5];

void* object::operator new(size_t size)
{
    if (count > 5)
        throw "Cannot allocate more than 5 objects!\n";
    void *p = malloc(size);
    allocatedObjects[count] = p;
    count++;
    return p;
}

void object::operator delete(void *p)
{
    free(p);
    count--;
}

void object::release()
{
    while (count > 0)
    {
        delete static_cast<object*> (allocatedObjects[count]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    object *o[10];
    int i = -1;
    char c = 1;
    while (c != '3')
    {
        cout << "Number of objects currently allocated : ";
        object::printCount();
        cout << "1. Allocate memory for object.\n";
        cout << "2. Deallocate memory of last object.\n";
        cout << "3. Exit.\n";
        cin >> c;
        if (c == '1')
        {
            try
            {
                i++;
                o[i] = new object;
            }
            catch (char* e)
            {
                cout <<e;
                object::release();
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (c == '2' && i >= 0)
        {
            delete o[i];
            i--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I have fixed the delete problem. By getting rid of destructor. And explicitly calling release at end of main.

But now my catch block is not catching exception. After allocating 5 objects exception is thrown (as traced through debugger) but not caught. New Changes in the code do not affect the related code.

Comment: Did you try to single-step with a debugger?

Comment: I'm not seeing the error handling on the input stream. Perhaps you'd like to call `cin.clear()` sometimes

Comment: `delete` calls `~object()`, which calls `release()`, which calls `delete`, giving the infinite loop. I'm afraid I don't know how to fix it, since I can't figure out what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in `release`. Consider this: If you have one allocated object, then `count == 1`, but the object will be at index 0 in `allocatedObjects`. Thus, you are accessing memory you do not own, which is undefined behavior. You'd have to use `allocatedObjects[count - 1]` to handle that.

Comment: @Mike you are right. I can't believe it i did such a horrible thing. Calling the chain of delete!! I'll try to fix this now.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @BjörnPollex : you pointed my second mistake. i am feeling miserable. Will fix that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop occurs because the destructor (`~object()`) is called before `object::operator delete()`. Your destructor is attempting to delete the most recent object allocated, which calls the destructor on the same object. The `operator delete()` is never being called.

I'm not sure what the `allocatedObjects` achieves here and the code will work without it. Get rid of the `release ()` as well.

**UPDATE**

OK, so there's a need for the release (exception handling).

Don't call release from the destructor. Instead, make the `operator delete()` function set the `allocatedObjects` entry to 0, after the calling `free` (mirroring the `operator new()`). The `release()` function is only called during exception handling and makes sure un-freed memory is freed correctly (i.e. loop through `allocatedObjects` array and `free` non-zero entries and then setting them to zero.

Comment: this is an assignment problem. and the problem (as stated in the link at the top of question) demands release(). i repeat the assignment is strange.

Comment: i have solved all my problems and the resulting code is here [link](http://pastebin.com/rJ8ZZkE5)